# Do entries in .Net custom configSection share attribute names?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have some .Net C# code *(which I will admit I wrote - many moons ago)* which doesn't quite work as expected and now, 5 years after it was written, I seem to have found a bug which I cannot explain.

Basically, I have an application configuration file, with a custom configuration section, which describes a number of entities. It seems that while it works, if I look for an attribute which doesn't exist, I get different results if the attribute really doesn't exist anywhere, vs. the attribute doesn't exist for a specific entity/element.

Where the attribute exists on no entity, the call to *ConfigurationElement.Properties.Contains(propertyName)* returns false, but if the attribute exists on at least one entity, it returns true, whether it exists on the current ConfigurationElement or not.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour is this way, whether through design, or my some coding error on my part.

**Edit:** It seems that the configuration element "Thing 1" has three properties (name,setting1,setting2) even though only the first two appear in the configuration file. I'm guessing that the underlying code assumes that all elements could have (some of) the same set of attributes.

**program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThingsConfigurationSection configSection = (ThingsConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("thingSettings");

            foreach (MyConfigurationElement thing in configSection.Things)
            {
                String name = thing.Name; // for thing 1...
                String setting1 = thing.GetProperty("Setting1"); // ...this returns "true"
                String setting2 = thing.GetProperty("Setting2"); // ...this returns ""
                String setting3 = thing.GetProperty("Setting3"); // ...this returns null
            }
        }
    }

    public class ThingsConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("things")]
        public ThingCollection Things
        {
            get { return base["things"] as ThingCollection; }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyConfigurationElement))]
    public class ThingCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection<MyConfigurationElement>
    {
    }

    public class ConfigurationElementCollection<TConfigurationElement> : ConfigurationElementCollection where TConfigurationElement : MyConfigurationElement, new()
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new TConfigurationElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((MyConfigurationElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public partial class MyConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public virtual String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return base["name"] as String;
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetPropertyValue(base.Properties["name"], value, false);
            }
        }

        public String GetProperty(String propertyName)
        {
            if (base.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
                return base[propertyName].ToString();
            else
                return null;
        }

        public void SetProperty(String propertyName, String value)
        {
            if (base.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
                base.SetPropertyValue(base.Properties[propertyName], value, false);
            else
            {
                ConfigurationProperty cp = new ConfigurationProperty(propertyName, typeof(String));
                base.Properties.Add(cp);
                base.SetPropertyValue(cp, value, false);
            }
        }

        protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute(String name, String value)
        {
            // add the values to the property collection
            this.SetProperty(name, value);

            // don't generate an error
            return true;
            //return base.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="thingSettings" type="Testing.ThingsConfigurationSection, MyConfigurationElement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </configSections>

  <thingSettings>
    <things>
      <add name="Thing 1"
           Setting1="true"
         />

      <add name="Thing 2"
           Setting1="false"
           Setting2="true"
         />
    </things>
  </thingSettings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... one option here seems to be to override the "DeserializeElement" method on the custom ConfigurationElement. At this point, the Xml element is in the XmlReader, and I can use that to get the names of the attributes which are present. If I save those names, in my GetProperty() method, I can return null if the named property was not present (at the time of deserialization).

```
public partial class MyConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private List<String> _propertyNames = new List<String>();

    :

    public String GetProperty(String propertyName)
    {
        if (_propertyNames.Contains(propertyName))
            return base[propertyName].ToString();
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void SetProperty(String propertyName, String value)
    {
        if (base.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
        {
            base.SetPropertyValue(base.Properties[propertyName], value, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ConfigurationProperty cp = new ConfigurationProperty(propertyName, typeof(String));
            base.Properties.Add(cp);
            base.SetPropertyValue(cp, value, false);
        }

        if (!_propertyNames.Contains(propertyName)) _propertyNames.Add(propertyName);
    }

    :

    protected override void DeserializeElement(System.Xml.XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey)
    {
        base.DeserializeElement(reader, serializeCollectionKey);

        if (reader.MoveToFirstAttribute() == true)
        {
            do
            {
                _propertyNames.Add(reader.Name);
            } while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute());

            reader.MoveToElement();
        }
    }
}
```